# Count number of rows returned by a sub query in Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql, criteria-api

I want to do something like the below query in Hibernate JPA.

```
select distinct count(*)
from (
         select distinct entity1.CODE                              as col_0_0_,
                         string_agg(entity2.PRODUCT_IMAGE_URL, ',') as col_1_0_,
                         count(entity1.CODE)                       as col_2_0_
         from entity1
                  inner join entity2 on entity1.id = entity2.entity1_ID                 
         where entity1.id = 1           
         group by entity1.CODE
     ) as cnt;
```

Any idea how would i do this using Criteria API?

Comment: can you add sample entity to get more details and relation

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like the following:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Entity1> root = criteriaQuery.from(MyEntity.class);
criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.countDistinct(entityRoot.get("code")));
Long count = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Yes but i have a subquery to execute and then counting the number of rows returned as a result.

Comment: Sure, but the example you have shown doesn't need the subquery. Essentially you just count the distinct codes. If you must use a subquery, you are out of luck with plain JPA Criteria. You can take a look at Blaze-Persistence though which offers a way to generate a count query: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.5/core/manual/en_US/#count-query